# Numbers: Is it possible to import animated gifs?

Tags: macos, video, numbers

I wanted to know if there is any chance to run an animated gif or somekind of video within a numbers table?

Answer (score 1):

Yes on macOS you can add movies and animated gifs into a Numbers table. By simply drag and drop movies and/or animated gifs into Numbers.

I dropped it next to the table. After it was imported I positioned it on top of the right cell. Not in the cell but on top of the cell.

[image: GIF in Numbers]

Comment: thanks, I tried that before, but dragged the image into a table cell. This forces the image to become a cell fill automatically. Is there any chance to put that media into a table cell but keep it an interactive media?

Comment: I dropped it next to the table. After it was imported I positioned it on top of the right cell. Not in the cell but on top of the cell.